# C++ I/O with Python

Tags: c++, python

I am writing a module in Python which runs a C++ Program using subprocess module. Once I get the output from C++, I need to store the that in Python List . How do I do that ?

Comment: What defines the items in the list? Each line is an item?

Comment: The Output is an array of Numbers. I need to store them in List

Comment: You should edit your post and show us an example of the exact format the C++ program outputs the numbers.

Comment: a[] ={123,98394, 7889934}. I am printing it one by one using cout

Comment: separated by newlines? Can you get data into your C program using the `subprocess` module?  If yes, then the answer I gave you should work.  Otherwise, the other answers should work.

Comment: Dude, I am getting the Output of C++ in newline, I need to store those values into a list

Comment: "Dude", *the Output of C++ in newline* doesn't mean anything.  See my answer anyway.

Comment: You need to post a better question showing us more details. You can edit your question to add these details and what you have provided in the question comments.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a quick and dirty method that I have used.

```
def run_cpp_thing(parameters):

    proc = subprocess.Popen('mycpp' + parameters,
                        shell=True,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

    so, se = proc.communicate()

    # print se # the stderr stream
    # print so # the stdio stream

    # I'm going to assume so = 
    #    "1 2 3 4 5"

    # Now parse the stdio stream. 
    # you will obvious do much more error checking :)
    # **updated to make them all numbers**
    return [float(x) for x in so.next().split()]
```

Answer (score 2):

one dirty method:

You can use Python to read (raw_input) from stdin (if there is not input, it will wait). the C++ program writes to stdout.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon your comment, assuming `data` contains the output:

```
numbers = [int(x) for x in data.split()]
```

I am assuming that the numbers are separated by whitespace, and that you already got the string in Python from your C++ program (i.e., you know how to use the `subprocess` module).

*Edit*: Let's say your C++ program is:

```
$ cat a.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    for (int i=0; i < sizeof a / sizeof a[0]; ++i) {
            std::cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
$ g++ a.cpp -o test
$ ./test
1 2 3 4
$
```

Then, you can do this in Python:

```
import subprocess
data = subprocess.Popen('./test', stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
numbers = [int(x) for x in data.split()]
```

(It doesn't matter if your C++ program outputs the numbers with newline as a separator, or any combination of white-space for that matter.)

Comment: My Doubt is about accessing an array in C++ as a list in Python.
Ok So How do I access a C++ array from Python

Comment: You need to print the array from C++ to `stdout` (using `std::cout` for example).  Then, use `subprocess.Popen()` to communicate with your C++ program, and then get the numbers as above.

Comment: Dude, I guess You Misinterpreted.

Python module runs C++ program using Subprocess. C++ outputs an array. I need to catch that output in Python module without using temp storage

Comment: Dude, he's telling you exactly what you need to do. Your C++ program is outputing *text*. Python is reading the data as text.

Answer (score 0):

In the command for the process you could do a redirect to a temporary file.  Then read that file when the process returns.